# Azure webapp ssl certificate pfx without password

Tags: azure, web, pfx

I have valid pfx SSL certificate without password. I could not install this cert on azure web app as password field is require. How do i install my pfx without entering password ?

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to achieve this is to install the certificate on to your local machine - making sure you mark it as exportable - and then export it again with a password.

Answer (score 0):

Open Edge and search for certificates and click on "Manage Certificate"

[image]

Import your pfx file and after import, export the same with password. Make sure, you select export private key